# Same name for all files uploaded with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have a problem with dropzone: all file names are the same when uploaded to remote.

Here is my code :

```
var AUTH_TOKEN=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

      Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
      var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone",{
          url: "<%= professionnel_diagnostiqueur_diagnostiqueurdevi_diagnostiqueurreponses_path(@devi.diagnostiqueur.professionnel.id,@devi.diagnostiqueur.id,@devi.id) %>",
          autoProcessQueue: false,
          uploadMultiple: true,
          addRemoveLinks:true,
          parallelUploads:10,
          maxFilesize: 15,
          params:{
              'authenticity_token':  AUTH_TOKEN
          },
          successmultiple: function(data,response){
              $('#msgBoard').append(response.message).addClass("alert alert-success");
              $('#msgBoard').delay(2000).fadeOut();
              $('#fileslist').val(response.filesList);
              $('#photographedit').off('submit').submit();
          }
      });

      $('#photographedit').submit(function(e){
          if(myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0){
              e.preventDefault();
              myDropzone.processQueue();
          }
      });
```

There is this thread: [Dropzone uploaded file have same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555824/dropzone-uploaded-file-have-same-name#comment76266469_44555824)
But it is unanswered

And this thread that suggests adding a hidden field : https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/580

Though I am yet noob with JS. Could someone help me factor the right code to add a hidden field for my above code? The dragndrop is located on id `mydropzone` and form has id `photographedit`

Comment: I have the same issue, using the same Dropzone configuration. All files get the filename of the last added file! Do you have any news yet?

Comment: Nope. Not tryed the answer below but intuitively I know it won't solve it. I am learning JS through code academy so that I can fix it myself but not sure I will succeed. You can find inspiration in one of the links I provided in case you know how to tweak JS and add an hidden field.

Comment: Argh! Updating from Dropzone 5.0.1 to the current version 5.1.1 solved my problem! What version are you on?

Comment: neat !!! thanks. Works all fine now. still a few things to check but file naming behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can change file name before sending the file to the server

```
myDropone.on('processingfile', function(file) {
  file.name = file.name + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ariel, but I really want to keep the user names because the user can upload PDFs as well as images and keeping the original PDF name is very useful for the end user...

Comment: So add a string to the end of the name -> Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)

Comment: I am trying this. can you confirm where I should place your code? Somewhere inside the code that already exists or rigth at the end ?

Comment: You can put it inside the init function

Comment: I don't see any init ? (yeah sorry i am that bad with JS)

Comment: You have init function inside the Dropzone.options take a look at the documentation http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration